# How can I make my ViewModel map to my actual Model?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a tab in my application, upon clicking which, the user's details are displayed (using the placeholder HTML attribute) to him inside editable text-boxes. The user can simply view them or can edit whichever detail he wants to.

Now my question is: should I create a View Model class for this scenario or should I use the actual Account model class? I guess I will have to create a View Model class as I will require only 'some' properties from the Account model class, but if I do so, how will I make it 'editable' and subsequently, map the edited properties(if any) to the actual Account model class?

Also, please tell me where exactly do I need to store the View Model class if I need to create one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should I create a View Model class for this scenario or should I use
>   the actual Account model class?

Yes, it's best to create a model that represents the action you need and you do that to prevent under and over posting. So you work on properties where you expect users to work on. For example, if you have an `AccountModel` that has a lot of properties and you only need to work on ten of it on an `add` action and five of its properties on an `edit` action, then you create two ViewModels:

```
// your model or entity
public class AccountModel {
    // the list of properties goes here
}
// your view models
public class CreateAccountModel {
    public string Username {get;set;}    
    public string Password {get;set;}
    public string Phone {get;set;}
}
// this model is for the scenario 
// where you want users to edit their basic info
// but not the password (e.g. you have a separate
// functionality for changing the password)
public class EditAccountModel {
    public string Username {get;set;}    
    public string Phone {get;set;}
}
```

Now to map your viewmodels to your actual model or entity, you can use mapper tools or do it on your own (tiring but an option for small models). Here are the steps:

- You receive the model/entity from a post
- You query your entity from your database
- You copy the values from the viewmodel to the model/entity
- You save the model/entity back to your database

> where exactly do I need to store the View Model class

You can have it in your MVC project under the `Models` folder that was created. This is more of a preference really and there is no standard way of doing it - especially if you start layering your application. Put it somewhere where it makes more sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed and prompt reply! Regarding the use of mapper tools (since I'm a newbie and never used one), I have a question: suppose my view model has 5 properties and the actual model has, say, 10, how will the mapping tool resolve this? Will the tool automatically skip the properties that ARE NOT part of the view model?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes it will skip it, [checkout this one](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).